# How can I force my Android application to open a new instance of the same activity in singleTop launch mode

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

My Android app has a class called ListQuotes, which, as implied by the name, displays a list of quotes. It can be opened in three instances :

1. by selecting an individual from a list to see his quotes
2. by clicking the "Favourites quotes" button on the toolbar
3. by selecting a category from a menu ("quotes about love", "quotes about friendship", etc...)

Everytime the class is launched, the app checks the Intent to determine where it came from and to display the appropriate list.

I set up its launch mode as singleTop so that the app doesn't try to reload the class when I press the back button and that the intent is preserved.

However, by doing so, I cannot load the favourites from the toolbar if ListQuotes is already the foreground activity. In other words, if I select an author to display his quotes, and then click on the favourites button, it doesn't do anything.

Is there a way to make it so that the launch mode of an activity stays in singleTop, but that you force the app to open a new instance of the activity in a specific case ? Or, perhaps, to have the launch mode as standard, but have a way to recover a previous intent? Or should I just make a separate activity for my favourites ?

I hope this was clear, I haven't programmed in a long while, so it's possible I'm missing something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `singleTop` launch mode. This will allow you to create another instance. Your statement:

> I set up its launch mode as singleTop so that the app doesn't try to
>   reload the class when I press the back button and that the intent is
>   preserved.

makes no sense, as pressing BACK will not cause this strangeness.

Comment: But... it does. If I remove the singleTop launch mode, the app crashes because it can't find the extra data of the intent. Is this due to something else?

Comment: Must be due to something else. Please post the code, explain the situation and post the stacktrace and exception from the logcat.